# Why does linear regression involve the $y$-coordinate error?

Tags: statistics, linear-regression, motivation

When dealing with linear regression, we are concerned about how far away a given point's $y$ component is from the "best fitting line".

My question: **why do we choose the $y$ component instead of the $x$ one, or, better still, the length of the perpendicular dropped from a given point to this "best fitting line" (which makes the most sense out of all three options)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're generally trying to model a situation where x is our input data, and y is some measurement, so x is assumed certain, and the error is assumed to be in the measurement of y.

Comment: This does make sense, thank you for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do all three.

Using the perpendicular is essentially PCA (Principal Components Analysis.)

See the answer by JDLong to [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/2691/making-sense-of-principal-component-analysis-eigenvectors-eigenvalues) post on CrossValidated for detail.